# What is The Cause of Outgassing in Space?

Tags: temperature, vacuum, space

What is the main cause of outgassing in space?

Does it only happen because of temperature, vacuum, or both?

Is it possible to test outgassing in vacuum chamber or does it have to be a thermal vacuum chamber?

Many sources define outgassing and the main causes such as moisture but no one really mentions the reason behind it in the first place.

Also, can we use conformal coating to protect against outgassing?

Comment: This question is quite general. Which outgassing problem are you interested in?

Comment: Outgassing that could happen to electronics mainly in space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outgassing is driven by vacuum and heat. The harder the vacuum and the hotter the environment, the more severe it will be.

It is readily and routinely tested in vacuum chambers equipped with heat lamps that simulate solar irradiation.

The common sources of outgassing are plastics, elastomeric seals, glues, lubricants, and paints- including conformal coatings. All of these things can contain volatile compounds that are drawn out of them by the vacuum and made mobile with heat.

It can be minimized by selecting materials that contain little or no volatiles, and by vacuum-baking any volatiles out of the material before it is built into a spacecraft.

Comment: Vacuum does not impact outgassing. Unless the outgassing species are nearing saturation, the presence of an atmosphere is not important. Even when saturation occurs unwanted transport of material may occur.

Comment: @my2cts, Aeroneutronic Ford (AKA Ford Aerospace) did their outgassing/life tests in a radiantly-heated vacuum chamber for this reason in 1975. If you disagree with their procedures, you could take it up with them (if they still exist).

Comment: Are you suggesting that all outgassing experiments should follow exactly the procedure from 1975, regardless? You should publish that thought.

Comment: I am not. what I am saying is that this was the procedure then. If you want to post your own answer, go ahead. -NN

Comment: I hope my comment is adequate.